# script ssh to multiple IPs and fetch config

Tags: bash, for-loop, ssh

I've got a task where I have to ssh into about 500 remote systems and pull a running config. I can only use password auth. I have created an expect script that will log in and run the command. The script is setup to so that I can pass the IP address to the script as an argument. My expect script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set ipaddress [lindex $argv 0]  
spawn ssh user@$ipaddress
expect "user@$ipaddress's password:"
send "passowrd\r"
set prompt {\$ $}
expect -re $prompt
send "show running-config\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "quit\r"
interact
```

The way I copy the running config from the remote hosts is calling up the script and redirecting that to a file on my local system.

```
./expect_script $IPADDRESS > file
```

This works great but I need to automate the process of feeding this script a list of IP's and having it continue to run until done. I am looking for guidance on setting up the for loop. So far I am thinking this would allow me to run through the list of IP's:

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=$(cat iplist)

for hosts in "$hosts"; do /root/expect_script "$hosts"
done
```

The problem is I do not know how to have the loop also create a new output file for each host config that's pulled. What I have done is setup the hostfile to look like this:

```
  192.168.100.5 > file1
  192.168.101.6 > file2
```

I thought if I put the redirect into the file it would work. However it does not. The loop works as far as connecting to the system via ssh and running the command, but it does not save to file1, file2, etc..

Is it possible to setup the loop to somehow create a new file for each host it runs against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=$(< iplist)

for h in $hosts; do /root/expect_script "$h" > "${h}.txt"
done
```

Comment: Or consider reading into array `hosts`, (e.g. `hosts=( $(<iplist))` and then `for h in "${hosts[@]}"; do ...` (yes since there is no whitespace, either will work